# ¿Por qué "milonga" indica un engaño o cuento?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, argentina, uruguay

De vez en cuando leo u oigo decir:

> No me cuentes milongas.

Por contexto ya sé que se refiere a que no se le expliquen cuentos chinos, que no se intente embaucarle. Esto aplicaría a contextos en el que alguien pone excusas o explica cosas poco probables.

Resulta que una milonga es un tipo de composición musical, pero parece que con el tiempo fue aumentando su registro hasta llegar a expresar este concepto. Inicialmente lo oí a argentinos o uruguayos, pero últimamente también lo oigo a españoles.

El DLE define *milonga* con todas estas acepciones relacionadas:

> [**milonga**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PGTZzdd)
>   1. f. Composición musical folclórica argentina de ritmo apagado y tono nostálgico, que se ejecuta con la guitarra.
>   2. f. Copla con que se acompaña la milonga.
>   3. f. Composición musical argentina de ritmo vivo y marcado en compás de dos por cuatro, emparentada con el tango.
>   4. f. Canto con que se acompaña la milonga.
>   5. f. Baile argentino vivaz de pareja enlazada.
>   6. f. Palo flamenco inspirado en la milonga argentina.
>   **7. f. coloq. Engaño, cuento.**
>   8. f. coloq. Arg. Discusión o riña. Se armó la milonga.

Pero así y todo, y supongo que debido a mi desconocimiento de la composición musical, mi duda se mantiene: **¿por qué "milonga" indica un engaño o cuento?**

Comment: Es curioso, porque yo el uso de "milonga" como "cuento" lo conozco y he oído usar desde hace mucho tiempo, no sé si es que en Andalucía se usaba más que en el resto de España.

Comment: Yo también lo conozco desde "siempre". No veo que ahora se use más.

Comment: Tenéis razón: Google trends muestra que [en España se está utilizando por igual desde 2004](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=ES&q=milonga). Si miramos en los libros, [Ngram Viewer muestra](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=milonga&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmilonga%3B%2Cc0) una caída desde 1980 para repuntar dramáticamente a partir de 1992 y hasta 2008 (último año que contempla).

Comment: Aunque igual había que buscar "contar milongas" o algo similar.

Comment: Reforzando lo que dice pablodf76 en su respuesta, nací y crecí en Argentina, y no conocía ese uso de "milonga". Solamente como música o como baile.

Comment: Por si te interesa, busqué la etimología de *milonga*, notando que el DLE no dice nada sobre ello, y me di con una breve explicación en portugués (de Wikipedia): “"Milonga" origina-se do termo **quimbundo** *milonga*, "palavras", através do espanhol rioplatense *milonga*. Nas religiões afro-brasileiras, o termo "milonga" significa "feitiço" ou "sincretismo".” (El "quimbundo", también "kimbundo" &c) es un idioma procedente de Angola.) También mencionan coma "Recentemente, a milonga surge como elemento integrador da cultura musical entre os três países (Argentina, Brasil e Uruguai)..."

Comment: @tchrist qué buena la etimología, detallándola como _hechizo_ (¿es la traducción de [feitiço](https://translate.google.es/#pt/es/feiti%C3%A7o)?) y mezcla. Teniendo en cuenta su origen cubano, no me extraña su conexión con distintos conceptos tradicionales y mestizos.

Comment: Sí, [*feitiço*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/feiti%C3%A7o) es cognado de [*hechizo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K4qdKc0), y lleva semejantes connotaciones: puede ser una cosa artificial o tal vez mágica, algo que encanta.

Comment: En Perú se dice milonga al lugar o evento donde habrá baile y algarabilla.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hay una relación entre "inventar historias, narrar falsedades" y la composición o ejecución musical libre e improvisada. En el ámbito rural argentino a esto último se le llama *[payada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payada)* y solía transformarse en una competencia. La [milonga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milonga_(m%C3%BAsica)), que hoy es urbana, parece tener orígenes similares, aunque actualmente no tiene la misma connotación de diálogo e improvisación. Como el tango, hay una diferencia entre la milonga como evento y la milonga como verso cantado, y hoy los aficionados a la milonga ven los locales de milonga como puntos de encuentro para el baile, no como lugares para escuchar historias.

Sin embargo, en Argentina se usa la palabra *verso* como "engaño, historia falsa urdida para sacar provecho de alguien", y el verbo *guitarrear* con el significado de "urdir una historia, inventar un cuento sobre la marcha" y también "hablar de algo de lo que uno no sabe fingiendo que sabe". No me extrañaría que *milonga* (que une versos y guitarra) haya adquirido el significado de "engaño" de esta manera. Las milongas (lugares donde se baila tango y milonga) son además lugares de socialización donde, obviamente, se mezclan el baile y el *levante* (*levantar* es en Argentina lo que *ligar* en España), tarea que para los seductores suele requerir algo de *verso* y *guitarreo*.

Más allá de todo eso, en Argentina, al menos en la región litoral donde vivo (no propiamente rioplatense aunque sí dialectalmente), jamás he escuchado *milonga* con el significado figurativo claro de "engaño, cuento". Me parece fascinante que así se emplee en España.

Answer (score 0):

En Uruguay se usa mucho la expresión “no me llorés la milonga” y tiene ese mismo sentido.

Milonga significa palabra o palabrerío en quimbunda y era el término con el que los brasileros se referían de manera despectiva a ese género musical, muy popular y extendido en el campo.